# Layout not working with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am new to ruby on rails.
I recently converted my erb files to haml files manually. I am facing a weird issue now. I have two controllers and a couple of views. The home page shows the layout correctly but the other views do not. I am trying to use "application.html.haml" for the layout (which is picked up by default).

1. application.html.haml resides in app/views/layouts
2. All the controllers except ApplicationController have ApplicationController as their parent class. ApplicationController has ActionController::Base as its parent class
3. The home page shows all the tags from the application.html.haml layout. However, the other pages do not include those tags. Their source code does not contain html, body, head etc.
4. I do not have the layout specified in any of the controllers.

When I add the tags to the views, everything works. But, I shouldn't have to do that, right?

application.html.haml

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title XYZ
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = yield
```

my_controller.rb

```
require 'somefile'

class MyController < ApplicationController


  def initialize
    @information = Information.new  # inside models folder
  end

  def fetch_information
    input = params[:search]
    input = input.strip
    flash[:error] = nil
    @hosts = @information.host(input)
    if @hosts.count == 0
      flash[:error] = "N/A: #{input}!" 
    else
      # add to cookies
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `application.html.haml` file please?

Comment: can you add the code for a controller that isnt using this layout but should be?

Comment: I have added the controller's code

Comment: @user3795049 what is `require 'somefile'` doing?

Comment: It basically has a function that returns a string to add to the cookies.

Comment: In my gem file I had gem "haml-rails". I changed it to gem "haml" and it started working. Weirdly though, it is working even after changing it back to gem "haml-rails". I rebuilt my whole project and ran the server again in both the cases.

Comment: Have you got [`haml` support in your `Gemfile`](https://rubygems.org/gems/haml)?  (`gem 'haml'`)?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! It was because I did not call `super` in the `initialize` method of my controller.